# Extending an existing Web application with Android app

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I have a new project involving the build of an Android app for a website of a hiking club. The website has a login functionality after which the user can browse through available hikes, subscribe to a hike, view the other subscribers, contact the organizer etc. 
The original site is based on a MySQL database with a front end of .asp pages. Most data is passed through the pages as GET parameters on the query string.

New to Android development, some things really puzzle me, even after reading several tutorials. I am thinking towards an architecture baes on REST webservices but there a several obstacles to overcome and chooses to be made.

Apart from using REST, some other options are available:

1. Call the original .asp pages from the app instead of building a dedicated Web service. This leaves me with much less code to write, the original business logic (queries e.a.) as well as the login system can be used (with the "remember me" functionality based on cookies). Downside is that the (X)HTML code in the response needs to be parsed to show in the app GUI, where the majority of the response code is useless ballast code. Also, it does not feel very good from an archtitectorial point of view.
2. Using a SOAP based webservice. I am totally unfamiliar with SOAP and it appears to be much too heavyweight for a mobile device.
3. Using REST services. I am leaning towards this option, and have made
   some already working services using the SLIM framework. But there
   are some problems.  First, REST is stateless by definition and does
   not seem to support sessions. But the "Remember me" option is
   required for the app after login in for the first time, the user
   needs not to login again unless he explicitly logs out.

But how can we achieve that?

First option is to designing some completely client-site login/logout system which saves the credentials locally until the user logs out. And sending the credentials with each request to the Web service as POST parameters, or somehow in the HTTP Authorization request header, though I am not familiar with that.

Second option is to deviate a bit from RESt principles and use a session mechanism anyway. After sending the credentials to the web service, a cookie is created and send to the client app. The dartabase cannot be extended so there is no option to save a token in the user table. Maybe the usernae/password can be encrypted and send as a cookie to the app, and decrypted at each subsequent request?

I am a bit lost in this, and look forward to serious suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that from a long term perspective, it is important that you lean towards REST Interfaces. While JSoup and/or WebView approaches will definitely work, it is important to have the flexibility to redefine/design the mobile application in ways that are completely agnostic of the Server side. REST will help you there and you do not need to play catch up with the Server side, everytime they change the HTML pages, etc.

Going REST will also help in future with writing additional mobile applications and even on different platforms like iOS, if your roadmap contains that.

Comment: Thanks, and I plan to follow this strategy. I have extended the Web services by passing the username/password credentials with each user-specific request as GET parameters for data pulling operations. And this works now, though it is not very secure.  This leaves the problem that most of the business rules must be written again because these are now hidden behind the .asp pages. It would be great when those business rules could be placed in one common place but I guess the existing Web application has to be rewritten in that case...

Comment: Old thread, but did you solve this with the suggested method? I'm doing something similar but struggling with Google's Volley to persist the ASP session

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the html pages from your Android app and reorganize the information of the web page, this option will gives you ability to quickly develop an App, later you may think on add REST interfaces to your web site and populate data in json.
You can also use WebView to laod your web pages if you don't want to parse html pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact this is what I described in option #3, and I had read about Jsoup as the best tool for this. I keep this as a fallback option but still hope to find a way to handle the login/session issue for REST in the upcoming days.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using REST architecture as you said. You can use a rest client library for Android as [RESTDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid/), take a look to the guide because there is a implementation example with special header needed for the particular web service used (Parse.com in this case).